# Pod with multiple images

Tags: kubernetes

Create a pod named xyz with a single container for each of the following images running inside there may be between 1 and 4 images specified +nginx+redis+Memcached+ consul

Comment: what do you mean by "running inside there may be between 1 and 4 images specified +nginx+redis+Memcached+ consul" ?

Comment: I believe you faced this question in CKA exam right?

Comment: @garlicFrancium These were exact wordings of a question that I too faced today in CKA exam. I was also wondering what it meant. I ended up creating a pod with multiple containers like you suggested but do you have any idea on whether this is possible? I have posted a separate question too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65666271/cka-exam-question-launch-a-pod-with-two-images-but-single-container

Comment: @vishal I think you did the right thing. When you say "this" is possible, i do not understand what is possible? I would stick to it's a wording issue but to me this question means one pod multiple containers otherwise there needs to be a custom image which i don't think the question demands!

Answer (score 2):

Not quite clear from the question but assuming you want one pod having multiple containers, below is the sample manifest which can be used:

`apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: xyz
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container-1
    image: nginx
  - name: container-2
    image: redis
  - name: container-3
    image: Memcached
  - name: container-4
    image: consul`

There will be 4 different docker processes for 4 different containers but there will be only one pod containing four of them.