# k8s:Two images but single container

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubernetes-pod

Below are the exact words of a question that came up in an online test.

> Create an single container app running in a pod named "bla-bla" with
> any 3 of the four images listed below. Images: nginx + redis+
> memcached.

I'm not sure whether this is a wordplay or a typo but what I would like to know is whether there is any syntax for launching multiple images in a single container? I know this can be done by having multiple containers within a single pod but according to the wordings in the question, I don't think that is what they expect. I saw this same exact question in Kubernetes official forum but no answer there too. Hence posting it here so it can reach a wider audience.

**Forum Question:** https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/can-we-have-a-single-container-with-multiple-image-like-nginx-redis-alpine/12017

Comment: No, there is only one image per container.

Comment: YOU ARE NOT ALLOWED TO SHARE QUESTION FROM EXAM. so I am editing question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the problem with the question. It asks to create a single *"container app running in a pod"*, not a *"single container"*.

So single pod with multiple containers is the answer. Here is the [example](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/).

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: two-containers
spec:

  restartPolicy: Never

  volumes:
  - name: shared-data
    emptyDir: {}

  containers:

  - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html

  - name: debian-container
    image: debian
    volumeMounts:
    - name: shared-data
      mountPath: /pod-data
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "echo Hello from the debian container > /pod-data/index.html"]
```

Comment: So I guess they tried to confuse with wordplay here right?

Comment: @vishal I guess they missed a comma after single "Create an single, container app.. "

Comment: @vishal, I don't think it was their intention to confuse you, but I can see how it can be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a single command like "kubectl run bla-bla --image xyz" I dont think there is one.

Easiest way imo is to do something like that.

1. kubectl run bla-blah --image nginx --dry-run=client -o yaml > multi-container-pod.yaml.
2. edit the yaml and run kubectl apply -f

Comment: This one also will have only one image per container. but according to the question , They are meaning multiple images in a single container. Atleast that is what I understand. So you too support that it is not possible?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question a bit. But yes, I agree wholeheartedly. 

I might me a bit confused right now, but I don't know of a way to run a single container with multiple images. Like at all. In any container engine.